# Resolved: Finding value of a node with a specific attribute XML 1.0 in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd

A client have asked for a data dump with a bunch of different columns from their database. It's all well and easy as long as it's just SQL, but I have encountered an issue where for two of the requested values, I need to pull it from an XML file. I'm new to the job, there's not much help to get in-house, and I'm trying to impress my boss here, so a lot's on stake haha.

This is a snippet of the XML file:

```
<record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" runtimeVersion="2">
  <insureds>
    <insured uid="xxx" category="000" name="this name" index="0">
      <dimensions>
        <dimension id="name">
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Morten</value>
        </dimension>
        <dimension id="price">
          <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">20</value>
        </dimension>
        <dimension id="duration">
          <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">10</value>
        </dimension>
     </dimensions>
   </insured>
   <insured uid="xxx" category="000" name="this other name" index="1">
     <dimensions>
       <dimension id="price">
         <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">40</value>
       </dimension>
       <dimension id="name">
         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Casper</value>
       </dimension>
     </dimensions>
   </insured>
   <insured uid="xxx" category="000" name="this last name" index="2">
     <dimensions>
       <dimension id="price">
         <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0</value>
       </dimension>
     </dimensions>
   </insured>
```

For every XML, I want the value where id="price". My problem, however, is that the XML's have changed over time, and therefore price isn't in the same index value for all of the examples. Instead I need to find the value of the FIRST TIME id="price" in every XML (since there can be multiple insureds/dimensions/prices, and the first instance can have moved to a new position). So in the above example, I am looking for the value 20.

I got the below working, but sadly it only worked in those instances where "price" was at position [36], and it has moved quite a few times during the production of 500000 records...

```
SELECT  Xml.value('(/record/insureds/insured/dimensions/dimension/value) [36]', 
'varchar(max)')     AS 'Price'
```

I was trying to modify it as per some online examples, this is what I got:

```
SELECT Xml.value('(/record/insureds/insured/dimensions/dimension/@id=@trip_cost)[1]', 
'varchar(max)')     AS 'Price'
```

This gives me error: "Top-level attribute nodes are not supported."

Now I'm stuck... Any ideas as to how I achieve the purpose of getting the value of the first dimension where id="price", regardless where it is positioned in the XML?

Any tips, thoughts or the like is much appreciated!

**  EDIT - THIS IS RESOLVED AS @JeroenMostert's COMMENT **

Comment: Rather than a snippet, could you provide a few examples that shows the difference for different pieces of data? Only providing 1 (incomplete) example won't help us test for other scenarios.

Comment: `dimension[@id="price"]`. I'm not sure why you're involving `@trip_cost` here.

Comment: @Larnu 
Thanks for the response. Here is an extended example:

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good catch, thanks! Now it runs but returns "false" for that value (the values are actually integers)

Comment: `dimension[@id="price"]` selects the appropriate node. What you then do with it is another matter. If you want the contents of the `value` child element as an integer, that would be `.value('...dimension[@id="price"]/value)[1]', 'int'`. If it doesn't work, edit your original question to make clear what you have now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert
Thanks! I think I already might have already tried that solution, but had forgotten the "" around "price". It seems to be working now, but I'll verify against a larger group of data in a bit. It seems promising so far!

Comment: @JeroenMostert You solved it! Add an answer if you want Stack creds ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `.value()` will return one single value. Your question is not all clear to me, but my magic crystal ball tells me, that you might be looking for this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<record xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" runtimeVersion="2">
  <insureds>
    <insured uid="xxx" category="000" name="this name" index="0">
      <dimensions>
        <dimension id="name">
          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Morten</value>
        </dimension>
        <dimension id="price">
          <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">20</value>
        </dimension>
        <dimension id="duration">
          <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">10</value>
        </dimension>
     </dimensions>
   </insured>
   <insured uid="xxx" category="000" name="this other name" index="1">
     <dimensions>
       <dimension id="price">
         <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">40</value>
       </dimension>
       <dimension id="name">
         <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Casper</value>
       </dimension>
     </dimensions>
   </insured>
   <insured uid="xxx" category="000" name="this last name" index="2">
     <dimensions>
       <dimension id="price">
         <value xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0</value>
       </dimension>
     </dimensions>
   </insured>
 </insureds>
</record>';
```

--This query will return a derived table of all content (well, the rest is up to you but should be easy) as a classical *entity-value* list. You might pack this into an CTE and use any kind of `WHERE` against the derived table:

```
SELECT i.value('@uid','varchar(max)') AS insured_uid
      ,d.value('@id','varchar(max)') AS dimension_id
      ,d.value('(value/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS dimension_value
FROM @xml.nodes('/record/insureds/insured') A(i)
CROSS APPLY i.nodes('dimensions/dimension') B(d);
```

--This will find all `<dimension>` nodes, where there is an attribute `@id` with the value `"price"` and list these values:

```
SELECT d.value('(value/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS dimension_value
FROM @xml.nodes('//dimension[@id="price"]') A(d);
```

If this does not help you out, it is always better to include the expected output fitting to the provided sample data. Best is a MCVE (a *stand-alone*, reduced but complete example like the code I've provided above).

Comment: My apologies for not documenting my issue well enough. I'm not all too experienced in that. Actually, for this specific issue, I only needed one value from each XML. Using a select statement (with Jeroen's suggestion), I get the correct value for each record. 
You should have many thanks for your suggestion too, however. It can be very useful later on I imagine. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @Nitr  no problem, Jeroen's answer will pick the first value, this seems to be rather random. But that's on you to evaluate. I appreciate your wish to pay the acceptance credits to Jeroen, if his comment solved your issue! That's the SO-way to say *thank you* :-D, votes to justify and acceptance to close.